# dependency injection : Register type in app start and use it across application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dependency-injection

I am using dependency injection in my WCF services. I am using it like this

```
public SInfo GetInfo(string name)
{
    var Container = new UnityContainer();
    Container.RegisterType<IStudent, Student>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    var StuRep= Container.Resolve<IStudent>();
    return StuRep.GetInfo(name);
}
```

I kind of registering and resolving in the method itself. I am wondering whether we can do it like in application start and use it across

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // what to do ??
}
```

Comment: Which technology? You've tagged with `wcf`, but IIRC when using WCF, you don't have `Application_Start` methods.

Comment: Some methods might be obsolete in newer version. Always use newer version tag to refer your question for better searched by the people. For example; http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net-4.6.1/commit

Comment: What's the point behind such registering and resolving in three consecutive lines of code? How's that better than just `new`?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do it, you are not doing it the proper way. You should be ideally resolving it in the appropriate class and method, so that the best practices are followed (not just of IoC but in regards to Coding standards). So ideally while you can try to register everything at one place like global.asax but resolving should happen when are where it is required.